# c# Setup Project, not tested configuration message

Tags: c#, installation

I want to display a message in my setup, if the user installs my software on a system that configuration I haven’t tested and the user should be choose if he continue the installation or cancel the installation.

do you have any ideas?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom UI form and a new custom action. [Here's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/156a95f4-a0e2-4ebb-9539-505005d8900e) a detailed description on how to achieve this.